# Spring @AliasFor not working for @Profile annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, annotations

> Environment: Kotlin 1.5.30, SpringBoot 2.5.4(Spring 5.3.9)

#### Background & Issue

I'm trying to create a composed annotation to simplify similar template annotation codes. The annotation class is like this:

```
@Profile("default")  //NOTE 1: use a placeholder, see the investigations below
annotation class ProfileAware(
    @get: AliasFor(annotation = Profile::class, attribute = "value")
    val profiles: Array<String>,
    //properties delegated for other annotations
)
```

expected usage:

```
@Component
@ProfileAware(profiles = ["dev"])
class TheBean {

    init {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger("TheBean").info("TheBean: I'm registered")
    }
}
```

in application.yaml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

**But after the application starts, TheBean is not registered as expected.**

#### Investigation & Try

- First I've search in github spring repository, and found this: [Regression: custom composed @Profile annotation without runtime retention no longer supported with component scanning](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23901). So I tried to add `@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)` on @ProfileAware, but no effect.
- Tried to remove `("default")` value from meta annotation *(and, whether add the default value to `profiles` attribute or not)*, but got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify at least one profile`.
- Tried to remove `@Profile("default")` from meta annotation, but got `AnnotationConfigurationException: @AliasFor declaration on attribute 'profile' in annotation ... which is not meta-present.`
- (**Important**) Try to use @Profile("dev") directly on bean instead of `ProfileAware` , works as expected.
- (**Important**) Try to change the value on meta annotaion as "dev", it works, but obviously it is hardcoded and not match my need.

Is there something I did wrong? Or is it possible to create composed annotation with dynamic @Profile value?

Thanks for your reading and help.

Comment: You should specify the default in the `profile` attribute not on the annotation and ofcourse the retention does indeed need to be `RUNTIME` else it won't be detected all together.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the comment, but 1) in Kotlin, runtime retention is [enabled by default](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.annotation/-retention/), so we can explicitly add `RUNTIME` but it does not matter. 2) I tried to add default value in `profiles` attr, but still need to pass values in `@Profile` annotation due to the 2 annoy exceptions above.

Comment: Which? As you state 3 errors... Also the `@Profile` needs to be there but empty. Could be that Kotlin is throwing things off but it should "just work (tm)"...

Comment: @M.Deinum No, I believe it must be spring error instead of Kotlin, since the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify at least one profile` stack trace is just `at org.springframework.core.env.ProfilesParser.parse(ProfilesParser.java:46) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]`

Comment: It actually makes me wonder if `@AliasFor` is supported for the `@Profile` when being used as a composed annotation. For the Kotlin part I wonder is Kotlin removes /adds something which makes it hard/impossible to read the composed annotation (hence the hint to Kotlin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Profile` is looked up by `org.springframework.context.annotation.ProfileCondition` whose `matches(...)` method uses `org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAllAnnotationAttributes(String)` to look up the `@Profile` annotations, and the Javadoc for that method states the following (bold emphasis added by me).

> Retrieve all attributes of all annotations of the given type, if any (i.e. if defined on the underlying element, as direct annotation or meta-annotation). **Note that this variant does not take attribute overrides into account.**

Thus, you currently cannot use `@Profile` with `@AliasFor` for annotation attribute overrides.